# Change Y-Axis to Percentage Points in plot()

Tags: r, plot

I'm plotting a graph using this:

```
### prepare survival object

    jan.surv <- Surv(time=data1$start_year,time2=data1$time_since_conflict,data1$instrastate_war_recurrence==1)

### Binning the Governance.Score variable
data1$gov_score_binned <- ifelse(data1$Governance.Score<3,0,
                                 ifelse(data1$Governance.Score>7,2,1))

### Run and plot Kaplan Meier
    surv.kaplan1 <- survfit(jan.surv ~ gov_score_binned,data=data1) 

    plot(surv.kaplan1, col="blue", bg="lightblue",    xlab = "Years since conflict",  ylab = "Probability of Peace")
```

And I am getting this plot:
OR:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1kQDOeErpaS-5oA-hUtD0s3Xj7ig6entkRcGF8pfnGp8/edit?usp=sharing

How am I able to change the labels of the Y-Axis from decimal to percentage?

Thanks in advance! :)

DATA:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1S2288ASa0qzSsrR6BLhXDkBVAGBMH_qVY7a-IFh3Jz4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: can you provide two pieces of information (a) how the present y-axis look like and (b) a subset/toy data that would produce a sample plot using your code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to suppress the y axis when drawing the plot using `yaxt = 'n'`, then draw another y axis with labels at the appropriate points:

```r
plot(surv.kaplan1, col = "blue", bg = "lightblue",    
     xlab = "Years since conflict",  
     ylab = "Probability of Peace", yaxt = 'n')

axis(2, at = 0:5 / 5, labels = paste0(0:5 * 20, '%'), las = 1)
```

[image]

---

**Data used**

Obviously, we don't have the data to recreate this plot, so I created a reproducible model with similar values and the same name for the purposes of this example:

```r
set.seed(1)
data1 <- data.frame(EP = c(rep(1, 10), rep(0, 4)),
                    time = c(rexp(10, 0.1), rep(60, 4)))
data1$Surv <- Surv(data1$time, event = data1$EP)
surv.kaplan1 <- survfit(Surv ~ 1, data = data1)
```